# How do I apply CYK or any other parsing algorithm without modifying my grammar?

Tags: linked-list, dynamic-programming, cyk

So I have a grammar inside a one-dimensional array, given by the form

```
struct array
{
    char left;
    char right[3];
    char number;
}
```

Example:

```
array.left = 'A';
array.right = "BC";
array.number = insert_some_conventional_null_character_here
```

This is translated to:

```
A->BC
```

### ------

Other examples:

```
A->3
C->BDE
X->9
```

Also, array.number is bounded by [0, 9].

array.right and array.left are literals in the interval [A, Z].

I need to return a linked-list containing all rules(grammar components) applied to get from an input string, called **startString** to another input string called **stopString**.

As you can see, this grammar is not given in the Chomsky Normal Form and I believe I cannot translate it into CNF because the grammar would change and I cannot return the linked list requested by the program.

How should I proceed? Just as a Post-Scriptum, there are at most 1000 such rules inside the grammar, so I guess that a recursive parser might not be the way to go. I've asked before and I was told to read about CYK algorithm, which I did. This is a problem I was given as a project. Please keep in mind I just started this level of programming. However, I do have all the basic knowledge.

Comment: BUMP'd my own post, so helpless of me :(

Comment: Welcome to SO, to complete your post, what did you have tried ? Also, maybe you can read again ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).